# Mongoose/MongoDB Empty SubSchema Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model in Mongoose that looks like this:

```
const orderLogSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
      removed: { type: String, required: true }, 
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
    }
  )

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    orderItems: [
        {
            name: { type: String, required: true},
            qty: { type: Number, required: true},
            image: { type: String, required: true},
            price: { type: Number, required: true},
            product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Product'},
        }
    ],
    shippingAddress: {
        address: { type: String, required: true },
        city: { type: String, required: true },
        postalCode: { type: String, required: true },
        country: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    paymentMethod: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    paymentResult: {
        id: { type: String },
        status: { type: String },
        update_time: { type: String },
        email_address: { type: String },
    },
    taxPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0
    },
    shippingPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0
    },
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0
    },
    isPaid: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    },
    paidAt: {
        type: Date,
    },
    isDelivered: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    },
    deliveredAt: {
        type: Date,
    },
    couponCode: {
        type: Object,
        required: false
    },
    orderVerifyLog: [orderLogSchema],
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
```

I need to be able to empty out the orderVerifyLog which is populated with the orderLogSchema. I have tried a bunch of things most recently I pulled the order into a variable, and I am able to access orderVerifyLog by using order.orderVerifyLog but I cant figure out how to empty out that orderLogSchema. I tried:

```
order.orderVerifyLog = []
order.save()
```

Is there an easy way to work with that "sub" schema and zero it out?
Basically I am pulling the log items from that schema for an order and displaying them on my front-end. Then I was to fire off an action to clears it out so they don't display every time the order is loaded (Only want them to show once). I also tired to loop over each item in the orderVerifyLog and use pull to remove them, but for some reason it always leaves one in there.

Comment: The code you tried works fine for me. Is it possible that something is adding items without you realizing it after you empty the array and save it? Keep in mind that .save is asynchronous.

Comment: Oh man!  I have no idea why that didnt cross my mind I think you hit the nail on the head.  Thanks for helping me out of this brain fog I find myself in today.